# Universal sets for self dual pointclasses?

Tags: reference-request, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

It's not hard to show that if $X$ is uncountable Polish and $\Gamma$ is a self-dual pointclass closed under continuous preimages, then there is no $X$-universal set for $\Gamma(X)$ with a diagonalization trick, this is exercise 22.7 in Kechris' book, so in particular there is no $X$-universal set for any $\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi(X)$.

According to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69655/delta0-alpha-universal-sets-does-not-exist?noredirect=1) if $X,Y$ are uncountable Polish spaces then there is no $Y$-universal set for $\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi(X)$, where that means a set $U\in\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi(Y\times X)$ such that $\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi(X)=\{U_y\mid y\in Y\}$, where $U_y=\{x\in X\mid (y,x)\in U\}$ are the slices of $U$. I don't see a simple way to prove this generalization of the result and I'm having troubles finding a proof in the literature.

How can the above result be proved? And does it extend to other self dual pointclasses closed under continuous images?

Comment: Actually, I may be having a silly moment, but: what does "$Y$-universal set for $\Gamma(X)$" mean exactly? (My guess is that it's an $R\in \Gamma(Y\times X)$ such that $\{\{x\in X: \langle y,x\rangle\in R\}: y\in Y\}=\Gamma(X)$, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: $U$ is $Y$-universal for $\Gamma(X)$ if $U\in \Gamma(Y\times X)$ and $\Gamma(X)=\{U_y\mid y\in Y\}$, where $U_y=\{x\in X\mid (y,x)\in U\}$. @Noah

Comment: OK, that's what I wrote, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the same, I started writing my comment before you edited yours and missed it. So for example if $X,Y$ are Polish uncountable, then there are $Y$-universal sets for $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\xi(X)$ (and of course also for $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\xi(X)$ as a corollary)

Comment: If I had a $\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi$ map $f$ of $X$ onto $Y$, then I could just take the inverse image of a universal $U\subseteq Y\times X$ under the map $(p,q)\mapsto(f(p),q)$ and get a universal subset of $X\times X$. Now any two uncountable Polish spaces are Borel equivalent, via a fairly low-level Borel map, so I'm all set as soon as $\xi$ is above that low level. But, alas, I neither remember nor have time to compute how low that level can be. (I'm hoping for $\xi=2$, but that might be a little too optimistic.)

Comment: @Andreas How is the level of a map defined? Is it the level of its graph?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I was thinking of $\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi$ maps as being the ones for which the inverse images of all $\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi$ sets are $\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi$. But I think that's likely to be equivalent to what you suggested (maybe with exceptions for very small $\xi$.)